# Wordpress Custom Taxonomy Template file

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I registered custom post type named e-books in wordpress and have also registered a taxonomy for that as well here goes the code

```
register_taxonomy('ebookgenre', 'ebooks',
    array(
        'label' => __( 'Categories' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'category' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
    )
);
```

But when i am listing all **taxonomy from ebookgenre** and linking them it is going to 404. please tell me which file or temlate should i use.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

See WordPress' [template hierarchy documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

You must create a file called `taxonomy-ebookgenre.php` in your theme directory (or have one of `taxonomy.php`, `archive.php`, or `index.php` files).

Also, you should go to the WordPress Admin > Settings > Permalinks page. Simple visit the page, and WordPress will regenerate your rewrite rules. Your taxonomy will not work until you do this first. This is due to WordPress caching URL rewrite rules, so if you added your taxonomy after these were cached, the URLs won't work. Whenever you visit the permalink settings page, the rewrite rules are flushed and re-cached.

Comment: In my case, I simply visit Permalinks page. It really works for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Visiting permalinks page solved for me. WordPress is a lil bit weirdo :/